# What is the right way to present custom post type in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, widget, custom-post-type

PRECONDITION:

1. I created custom post type "comparison"
2. I created 'widget.php' and registered it in 'functions.php'
3. I added widget to 'front-page.php'

TASK:
On my Front Page and I want to list all posts with type "comparison" in separate widget with pagination

PROBLEM:
I don't know the 'best practice', how to implement it technically. How to list all "comparison" in widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the custom post template code, You can assign the template on the page you want to display the posts list. You can try with below template code:

```
<?php 
# Template Name: Comparison List 
?>

<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 
          'posts_per_page' => 15, 
          'paged' => $paged, 
          'post_type' => 'comparison', 
          'orderby' => 'title', 
          'order' => 'asc' 
        );
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'comparison-list-item' ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php print_pagination($wp_query); ?>

<?php else: ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'nothing-found' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```